# The simplest replacement of color in PNG icons

Tags: gimp, inkscape, png

I need to replace the color of some PNG icons. Examples:

[image: JavaScript]
shall become [JavaScript2 http://www168.lunapic.com/editor/working/146856450596963-bt-5](http://www168.lunapic.com/editor/working/146856450596963-bt-5).

[image: YAML1] shall become: [YAML2 http://www168.lunapic.com/editor/working/146856450596963-bt-10](http://www168.lunapic.com/editor/working/146856450596963-bt-10).

Only color replacement: *orange → violet, orange → green,* and no other actions.

I never worked before with the advanced graphic editors, whether I can carry out replacement of colors?

Any non-commercial graphic editor for Windows would be fine (not Photoshop).

Comment: In [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/): https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-hue-saturation.html When you got the `Hue-saturation` window open, just adjust the `hue` slider like a crazy person and you should see the colors change.

Comment: @Joonas: Shouldn’t that be an answer?

Comment: @Joonas, thank you very much! Please, publish your comment as the answer that I could accept the answer and raise your reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/):**

- Open the document
- Open Hue-saturation tool (
  [Instructions](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-hue-saturation.html)
  )

  - When you got the Hue-saturation window open, just adjust the hue
    slider like a crazy person and you should see the colors change.

Comment: Two other options would be to use the [rotate colors](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-rotate-colormap.html) and [color exchange](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-exchange.html) features. For a simple single color image, the hue-saturation tool works in a pinch, but might not be appropriate for more complicate changes.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick:

```
mogrify -fuzz 50% -fill violet -opaque "#F4BF75" *.png
```

I used "identify -verbose file.png" to display the histogram and determine that #F4BF75 is the predominant orange color present.

The fuzzing is needed because your samples are antialiased and have a variety of approximately orange colors present.  You can omit "-fuzz 50%" and then the results will have orange halos like the results you posted.

Answer (score 0):

if the white in your icons is actually transparency:

- Set the alpha-lock for the layer (checkerboard icon at top of layer list)
- Make sure you have no selection
- Bucket fill with new color, the alpha-lock will protect the transparent pixels (actually, it will make sure all pixels keep their initial opacity).