# Gimp: Change a signature color from black to blue, preserving the tones

Tags: gimp, transparency, color-conversion

I have a scanned signature written in black pen. I have removed the white paper parts of the image using [alpha transparency](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-web-transparency.html).

After using it several times, it seems that it would look better if the color of the signature is blue rather than black.

How can I change the color of the signature from black to blue, while preserving the different color tones and shades (i.e. Black becomes dark blue, light gray becomes light blue)?

Comment: Related question: [The simplest replacement of color in png icons](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74770/the-simplest-replacement-of-color-in-png-icons)

Answer (score 2):

- Set the foreground color to dark blue (the color that will replace black), the background color to white.
- Set the image to RGB mode if not already such: *Image>Mode>RGB*
- Set the current gradient to *FG to BG (RGB)* (fourth from top in Gradients list)
- *Colors>Map>Gradient map*

Answer (score 0):

From the top menu, choose:

Colors -> Colorize

As you pick the color on the palette, it will instantly apply to your image and you can quickly re-iterate to achieve desired result. It's super smooth, all gradients are preserved. Very realistic outcome.